# How can I get BufferedReader to display live outputs from a running python script using ProcessBuilder?

Tags: java, python, bufferedreader, processbuilder

I have a Java script that starts a new thread to execute a python script using Process builder. The code below currently takes the output from python and displays it in the Java run output and within a JTextArea. BUT, it only does so in bulk, once the py script has finished running. Is there a way to get the output displayed live as it is written out from the py script? Thanks!!!!

```
public void launchPythonScript() {
    try {
        ProcessBuilder py = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/C", "PythonScriptLocation (C:\\....)",""+Directory(variable needed for py script));
        Process launch = py.start();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(launch.getInputStream()));
        String readLine;
        StringBuilder JavaOutput = new StringBuilder();

        while((readLine = reader.readLine()) != null){
            JavaOutput.append(readLine).append(System.lineSeparator());
            frame2.consoleOutput.setText(JavaOutput.toString());
            System.out.println(readLine);
        }           
    } catch (IOException ex) { Logger.getLogger(Frame1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);}
}
```

Comment: I think the solution may have something to do with threading. I think the issue is in the current thread, when launch = py.start() is executed,nothing else happens until its finished, then everything else follows.

Answer (score 0):

Process InputStream should give you data while the script is running.

You are reading one line at time so if your python script send all data in one single line then you see the output only at the end.

Try to break the output data into multiple lines.

Comment: The python script is a user interface and outputs information line by line as the user progresses through the script, so shouldn't InputStream read it in the same way? thanks.

Comment: it should indeed, check if every line the script outputs has the correct line separator at the end

Comment: I believe it does, as a test I added System.out.println("some text") to the while loop. The result was "some text" above and below every line outputted by python, so it must be reading them correctly?